# How to provide access to composite types to another schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Im new to postgres, previously i was using oracle.Need help in providing grants to composite type.

I have created a function to return multiple datatype, for that i have created composite type.

Both my object and functions were created in schema sys_tech and it worked perfectly fine.

But when i tried to run the function from another schema(readonly_portal), im getting the name of the datatype instead of the values in output.Do i need to provide grants, How does it work?

Since the error is not with the code, i have not pasted my code.

Edit 1:

## Type:

```
 create type mob_mart.ty_valid as (p_ret1 boolean,p_ret2 varchar(500));
```

## Function:

```
create or replace function mob_mart.validate_sys(p_cid int,p_user varchar2 default null)
return mob_mart.ty_valid  as $$
declare
result_type =mob_mart.ty_valid;
l_cnt int4;
begin
select count(1) into l_cnt from mob_mart.endcompany a ,mob_mart.end_user b where a.id=b.company_id and a.id=p_cid and (b.id=p_user or p_user isnull);
if l_cnt>0 then
 result_type.p_ret1=true;
 result_type.p_ret2 ='Company and user exists';
 else
    if exists(select customer_id from mob_mart.endcompany where customer_id=p_cid limit 1) then
        select id,customer_id into l_uid,l_cust from mob_mart.end_user where id=p_user limit 1;
        if l_uid isnull then
                result_type.p_ret1=false;
                result_type.p_ret2 ='User does not exists in the database';
        elsif(l_cust!=p_cid) then
                result_type.p_ret1=false;
                result_type.p_ret2 ='User Id exists ,but for different company';
        else
                        result_type.p_ret1=false;
                        result_type.p_ret2 ='All condition passed, different error';
        end if;
    end if
end if; -- main if
return result_type;
end
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

This function will return two values, 1) boolean value 2) Description.

If the value is condition is true, the desc would be null, if the condition is false, i need to print the reason for it.Its a simple validation which passes company_id and user_id as input, If both exist then it will simply return true, else it will print the reason for it.

```
select mob_mart.validate_sys(111,'test');
```

ouput is
(f,'User Id exists ,but for different company')-- worked fine,

Next i tried to provide grants to portal_user

```
grant execute on function mob_mart.validate_sys(int,varchar2) to portal_user;
```

when accessing the function from portal_user,it is displaying ty_valid as output

Comment: Yes, further clarification is needed. Can you reproduce the problem in psql? If yes, add the statements, the result and the desired result. If not, the code *is* relevant. Anything to help reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show us the `grant` statements you ran. And show us the query you use and the output you get. I have no idea what you mean with "getting the name of the datatype". **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe : code attached

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: grant statement for function is mentioned, but i dont know how to provide grants to composite_type

Comment: `grant usage on type mob_mart.ty_valid to portal_user;` What **exactly** is the output you get (a screen shot would be helpful in this case)

Comment: Note that by default, `PUBLIC` has `USAGE` privilege on all types. Unless you used `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to change that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: okay, let me check with grant usage command for the composite data_type.